# how setup heroku toolbelt to use -r <nickname> to specify an app

Tags: git, heroku

On my old machine I could type

```
heroku config -r prod
```

to see the config settings for the app nicknamed 'prod' (instead of --app actual_app_name).

On my new machine, with the same version of heroku toolbelt, I cannot recall how to tell heroku toolbet to accept `-r prodn` instead of `--app actual_app_name`

The git config files on the two machines seem to be the same, so it's not a git confgi setting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Dec. 2014

[andorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396904/andorov) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813997/how-setup-heroku-toolbelt-to-use-r-nickname-to-specify-an-app/26814985?noredirect=1#comment43302923_26814985) to the Heroku announce "[HTTP Git now Generally Available](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/5/http_git_now_generally_available)":

> With HTTP Git now the default, `heroku create`, `heroku git:remote` and `heroku git:clone` commands all configure your local environment to use HTTP Git.
>   If, for any reason, you want to use SSH Git with a particular app, simply pass a `--ssh-git` flag to these commands, e.g.:

```
$ heroku create --ssh-git
```

> If you want to always use SSH Git with Heroku on a particular machine, you can add the following global config:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
```

> HTTP URLs will still be written to `.git` folders but Git will rewrite, on the fly, all Heroku HTTP Git URLs to use SSH.
>   See the [Git documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for details for details, including instructions on how to remove this setting.

---

Original Answer (Nov. 2014)

The article "[This Week I Learned #2](http://work.stevegrossi.com/2014/01/11/this-week-i-learned-2/#with-the-heroku-toolbelt-you-can-identify-apps-by-git-remote-instead-of-name)" mentions:

> With the Heroku Toolbelt You Can Identify Apps by *Git Remote* Instead of Name

That would mean the -r is followed by the name of a remote, one returned by `git remote -v`.

So check your local remote `git remote -v`, and try using that name (referencing the remote repo where your heroku app is pushed).

See that [project example](https://github.com/dghubble/django-project-template#heroku):

> Create Heroku app repo and add Git staging remote,

```
heroku login             # if you haven't already
heroku create --remote staging  # within project dir
heroku create --remote production
git remote -v            # expect: origin, staging, production
```

> Here the project becomes associated with two Heroku apps, one for staging and another for production.
>   When git pushing, specify the correct remote and when using heroku commands use the `--remote remote-name` or `-r remote-name` options to specify the application to which deployments should go.
>
> To tell the heroku command to default to staging for this project,

```
git config heroku.remote staging
```

---

Comment: This didn't work for me with heroku's new HTTP git deploy, but you can default to the old ssh with `git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/`.  See here https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/5/http_git_now_generally_available

Comment: @andorov good point. I have include a more complete extract of the new Heroku policy in the answer for more visibility.