# Use SSH keys from command line during push for GitHub?

Tags: authentication, github, ssh

I have existing SSH keys on file with GitHub. I'm trying to push a change to someone else's GitHub project. I have *Collaborator* access to the account.

I am being prompted for a password:

```
$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': xxxxxx
Password for 'https://xxxxxx@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git/'
```

GitHub's help at [Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) only discusses SSH in the context of a Desktop client. I guess they have an app they want me to use, but I don't really want to use one.

How do I have the command line tool use my SSH keys for pushing changes to a GitHub account?

---

This is related to [How do I checkout a GitHub project from command line as a Collaborator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30656741). I was never able to checkout with credentials as a collaborator, and now I fall into this password authentication trap.

Answer (score 2):

To push as another account, you would need the private/public ssh keys from that other account stored in your `~/.ssh` folder.

You would also need an ssh config file (`~/.ssh/config`) similar to:

ssh config file declaring multiple keys:

```
Host githubUserA
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User git

Host githubUseB
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other
    User git
```

And you would use ssh url like

```
githubUserA:userA/myrepo1
githubUserB:userB/myrepo2
```

The second account could be used from the same repo by adding a new remote:

```
git remote add guserB githubUserB:userB/myrepo2
git push gUserB myBranch
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. Is there a way to configure GitHub to ***only*** use SSH keys for my access? If GitHub is configured properly, then it won't waste my time with password prompts and I won't have to do this client side (on multiple machines)?

Comment: @jww what you would configure is the remote url associated with your local repo: type `git remote -v` to check those are ssh url only. And/or you can use the `insteadOf` directive, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26814985/6309.