# Git on Windows 10 - credential.helper messed up

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using Git (portable) on Windows 10. By some mistake I messed up my configurations for username/password and their caching timeouts.

The mistake I did was that I also installed Git for windows (not portable) and I think that's where most of the issues started. But I am not sure. Now I uninstalled it and I am back to Git portable for Windows.

I used to be able to login and not type username/password each time (for bitbucket). Now I am trying to setup again credential.helper but I am running into all sorts of issues.

1) I get this quite often: "git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command."
No idea where it comes from. Previously I didn't have it.

2) I am still being asked for password (not just the 1st time).

3) Also, I am not sure what was my previous value for credential.helper. I guess it was `manager` but I am finding here on SO that there's also `wincred`. But this `wincred` seems really old thing. So I guess I should set it to `manager`.

4) Btw, when I put `manager` for credential.helper, I get some weird bitbucket (browser-like) pop-up where I need to enter my username and password (btw, where does this pop-up come from? I didn't install anything from bitbucket?).

[image]

But when I enter username/password, it doesn't accept them and says:

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
    An error occurred while sending the request.
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

So this time I need to enter them from the cmd promt and the next time I need to enter them again in this pop-up?!

I don't want this pop-up at all, all I want is my username/password to be saved somewhere and cached. How do I do it?

In my global (Windows user level) git config file I have this section but I am not sure if it's correct.

```
[credential]
    helper = cache --timeout=604800
    helper = manager
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have only one credential.helper: manager.

Try: `git config -l --show-origin`

For every credential.helper you see, remove it from its config file.

Then type:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

(Note 2021: the current manager is the cross-platform [GCM -- Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) project)

Finally, try a `git push` to a bitbucket repo, re-enter your username/password (once): that should be enough.
Although, [check out this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows-Popups/qaq-p/579905):

> (20 June 2018): Recent changes to Bitbucket authentication has also meant that you must use your email (NOT your username) when logging in.
> Currently, logging in with your username is still accepted but seems to cause several issues ranging from this repeated login prompt issue to the "too many login attempts" error when pushing

Comment: But I have 2 bitbucket accounts. And it seems the Windows Credentials Manager cannot support 2 different bitbucket accounts. I did many tries last night. I get stuck in anything that I try. Finally I solved it by using 2 different .git-credentials files (one file with 2 URLs also does not work, the two repos keep overwriting it /even when I do just pull/, and they get confused eventually).

Comment: But this solution with the 2 credentials files is rather ugly, far from perfect. So... any ideas? Also, how do I get rid of this strange login pop-up. I went back to an older git version and it disappeared. But what if I want to upgrade my git to the latest Windows Git portable?

Comment: @peter.petrov Then use ssh URLs instead of https ones: you can configure multiple public/private keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520508/6309

Comment: @peter.petrov And you can use the latest Git for Windows. True, Its GCM (Git Credential Manager (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) does include an Atlassian login (that is where that popup is coming from: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/0db46efb0ae51053b4e442081c5cffcb964f6736/Bitbucket.Authentication/Src/Assets/auth.html), but if you are using SSH URLs, it won't bother you anyway.

Comment: @peter.petrov But if you still want to use HTTPs URLs with multiple accounts, still with the latest Git, read https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/0db46efb0ae51053b4e442081c5cffcb964f6736/Docs/Bitbucket.md#multiple-user-accounts

Comment: OK, thanks for the resources. I will see. A friend of mine is recommending I use SourceTree, says it has its own credential manager so... I might try that too. The current solution is still OK for me but kind of clumsy, that's all.

Comment: @peter.petrov No, use the latest Git, and use its GCM (Git Credential Manager). SourceTree can use it too.

Comment: @peter.petrov But the idea remains: you can use HTTPS (with entries like user1@bitbucket.org, user2@bitbucket.org, as explained in https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/0db46efb0ae51053b4e442081c5cffcb964f6736/Docs/Bitbucket.md#multiple-user-accounts), or SSH.