# Having separate GitHub and Bitbucket Accounts on the same machine

Tags: github, git-config

Now while this can be considered duplicate at the first glance, I request everybody to please go through the description. 
I want to push to separate `Bitbucket` and `GitHub` accounts.
While I understand that we can have a global config (say its the primary account - `Bitbucket`) and a local config for a repository (`GitHub`) after setting separate `SSH-keys` for both, is there a way we could configure multiple `email-id's`/`userNames` in the `.gitconfig` file ?

**Note**: I have separate `emails`/`username's` for the `GitHub` and `Bitbucket` account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're conflating the email and name that get saved in commits (from `git config`) with authentication to GitHub and Bitbucket (via SSH or HTTPS). Do you really want to make commits that look different (e.g. `me+github@example.org` vs. `me+bitbucket@example.org`)? If so, why?

Comment: No thats not what I mean. I am not pushing two hosting sites from the same repo. That does not make sense. I have setup the configuration using global config and local git config. I basically wanted to be able to setup different GitHub and Bitbucket configs on the same machine. I was contemplating that if this could be done using one gitconfig file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple ssh keys setup for pushing to multiple repository hosting services (like I describe in "[Use SSH keys from command line during push for GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520508/6309)")

But if you want to push to GitHub and Bitbucket from the *same* local repo (one commit, 2 pushes), then you would need to chose one username/email for your commit, which can only have one set of author/email metadata associated to it.

If you are pushing from different repo, then yes, each one can have its own local Git config setting, with different user name/email.